# Use HTML5 embedded player instead of native player on mobile device

Tags: ios, html, html5-video

It might be a too simple question,however I couldn't good answer yet.
I have simple video player like this.

```
<video src="test.mp4" id="mainVideo"></video>

<input type="button" value="play" onClick="playVideo()">

<script>
var v = document.getElementById("mainVideo");
function playVideo() {
    v.play();
}
</script>
```

On Desktop browser,If you push the play button the video played in the place where  tag is placed.

On iOS, the native iOS (fullscreen payer) appeares and play video.
I don't want to use native iOS player though, How can I make it work same as the desktop player does??

Answer (score 1):

This Code is Made to use native Player. The Desktop Browser uses its own player. You probably cannot use the desktop browser player in place of the native ios player.Try googling for "How to user-defined players in html5 ios"..may it help you..

Comment: I see .... I found on iPad, it works what I meant though,,, on iPhone the player is forcibly full-screened.